# Equal angles geometry questions

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Consider an acute triangle ABC with midpoints D,E,F of sides BC, CA, AB respectively. Let CF intersect the perpendicular bisectors of AC and BC at M and N respectively.
Now, consider the point of intersection X of the lines AM and BN.
Prove that the angles ACX and FCB are equal to each other.

I tried to solve this problem algebraically (by fixing A,B and finding the coordinates of X in terms of C), however this turned out to be extremely messy.

Is there a way to solve this with elementary geometry?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In figure $KJ||AB\Rightarrow \angle ABX=\angle BKJ=\angle BLJ$

In triangle CHJ, OB is perpendicular bisector of HJ, therefore:

$\angle BHJ=\angle BJH=\angle HCB=\angle ABK$

in triangle NBC, NG is perpendicular bisector of BC, so :

$\angle NBC=\angle NCB=\angle HCB$

which results in:

$\angle NBC=\angle ABK$

Or:

$\angle ABX=\angle FBC$

Note : in figure B and C  are changed.

Comment: I think it might be a good idea to add why certain equalities hold. I do understand that $\angle BHJ=\angle BJH= \angle HCB$, but why is that also equal to $\angle ABK$? Maybe I just miss something.

Comment: I think sirous was just referring to the very first line (and $\angle ABK=\angle ABX$ clearly)
However, I am not sure hot to justify "OB is perpendicular bisector of HJ". 
Clearly, we are using 2 properties of H: that it lies on CX and also, that it is the refection of J over OB. How do we know that these properties are indeed equivalent?
Could you please clarify, how this step works? @sirous