# Geometry, points on a circumcircle, perpendicularity

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Consider an acute triangle ABC with midpoints D,E,F of sides BC, CA, AB respectively. Let CF intersect the perpendicular bisectors of AC and BC at M and N respectively. Now, consider the point of intersection X of the lines AM and BN.

Moreover, let K be the intersection of CX and the circumcircle of ABC and let H be the intersection of BX and the circumcircle of ABC. Let g be the line through K that is parallel to AC. Let J be the intersection of g with the circumcircle of ABC.
Prove that OC is perpendicular to HJ.

This is a part of the problem discussed here: [Equal angles geometry questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4494104/equal-angles-geometry-questions).
Somebody provided an incomplete proof for the original problem; however the part described above is still missing.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

We want to prove that $CJ=CH$, but since $CJ=AK$ it is enough to show that $CK\parallel AH$.
Notice that the perpendicular to $CA$ through $A$ and the perpendicular to $CB$ through $B$ meet on the circumcircle at the antipode $C'$ of $C$: by considering the quadrilaterals $CAC'B$ and $CAC'K$ it follows that $X$ is the midpoint of $CK$ and $OX$ is the perpendicular bisector of $CK$. Additionally  $AK=2 EX$. Since $OXCE$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, $\widehat{EXO}=\widehat{ECO}=\widehat{ACO}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\widehat{B}$ and $\widehat{CXE}=\widehat{B}$. The problem reduces to showing that $\widehat{HCK}=\widehat{HBK}=\widehat{B}$. I achieved this in a convoluted way, i.e. by introducing the antipode $B'$ of $B$, the intersection $L=AX\cap \Gamma$ and by checking that $B'L\parallel OX$. It can probably be done in more efficient ways, but I guess I have at least outlied some ideas.

Comment: Just to clarifiy, could you maybe share your work for the last part (i.e. HBK=B?)

Answer (score 0):

$\angle 1 = \angle 2 = \angle =3$ implies  (arc FC) = (arc CF).

[image]

That is, since OC divides arc HJ equally, OC will also divide chord HJ equally. Result follows.

Comment: Please, carn you explain why $\angle 1=\angle 2$ holds? Thanks! @Mick

Comment: @MartinLeyn They are alternate angles (wrt AH//CK). Same for $\angle 2 = \angle 3$.

Comment: Isn'T this what we wanted to show? Alternate angles means that CK and AH are parallel. How do we know this?

Comment: @MartinLeyn  As a quick fix to this matter. Just assume this is the continuation of JackD'Aurizo work.